# When I send a byte array containing two bytes with value of 0 it stops working

Tags: http, webserver, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

On my ESP8266 I use the ESPWebServer Library,when I receive bytes from a request and it contains two consecutive bytes valued 0 then the following bytes that are left also return 0 not their correct value. So if I send the following as bytes "79 1 80 1 0 0 10 73 2 80 1 0 148 112" I receive "79 1 80 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0" on my unit.

When I change the byte value from 0 to 1 the program runs correctly.
Is this a library error or was it designed to do this? 
I get the value using the normal arg function.

Edit:

my code:

```
if (server.method() == HTTP_POST) {

    if (server.hasArg("plain")) {

      String plain=server.arg("plain");
//      unsigned int plainSize=plain.length()+1;
//      char body[plainSize];
//      plain.toCharArray(body,plainSize);
//      delay(200);
      Serial.println(plain);
       unsigned long time=micros();
       String result = zsense.Sensor(plain);
       Serial.println("Time: "+String(micros()-time));
      server.send(200, "text/json", "{\"Result\": \"" + result+"\"}");
    }
    returnFail("No body found");
  }
  returnFail("getIOValueby is a POST request");
```

So when I do Serial.println(plain); i get "79 1 80 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0" in char not
"79 1 80 1 0 0 10 73 2 80 1 0 148 112" in char what I sent with Postman.

Comment: Describing code isn't helpful. Sharing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code that demonstrates the problem is helpful. Take your program that's not working, cut out everything that's not necessary to demonstrate the problem, verify the problem still happens and then share that code in your question. That will give us something to debug, and you may even find the problem yourself in the process of doing that.

Comment: Ascii value 0 ('\0') is used as C-string terminal character.